# Which software is recommended for large data set analysis?

Tags: sql, database, excel

So I'm very new to this, forgive if my questions are silly.

I've got some data I need to analyse, I would usually just use excel it doesn't seem to be able to do the job.

I have .csv files containing data for every seconds over a year period. 
The data simply consists of timestamps and valueX.

I need to analyse these values to see if values X goes below a certain value, and if it does I have various calculations to carry out. Value A is proportional to X and just instantaneous, then value B is a counter proportional to A.

Could you suggest a method/ language / software that would be the best and most accessible to do this ? I don't have much experience in data analytics/big data apart from using excel and a bit of matlab and python.

Answer (score 2):

you can below tools for that:

```
1) Tableau public
2) Trifacta
3) Rapid Miner
4) Qlikview
5) Weka
```

Answer (score 1):

For data analysis, you can learn "Scikit-learn".

"Scikit-learn" is used for machine learning, it contains a lot of useful data analysis methods.

Answer (score 1):

You Could try SPSS (Or its free cousin PSPP) or as Manoj suggested, Weka.

Both are statistical analysis tools